# Botium not picking up buttons from Botkit 4.0

Tags: botkit

In the [Botkit connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-botkit) sample  `Botkit40` folder, there isn't a test on buttons.

ButtonsAsserter work in Botkit 0.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest [Botium Botkit Connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-botkit) support for quick replies (buttons) and file attachments has been added.

So, if your Botkit bot replies something like this:

```
    await bot.reply(message, {
      text: 'Look, quick replies!',
      quick_replies: [
        {
          title: 'Hello',
          payload: 'hello'
        },
        {
          title: 'Help',
          payload: 'help'
        }
      ]
    })
```

You can use this BotiumScript test case for asserting the presence of the buttons:

```
buttons

#me
buttons

#bot
Look, quick replies!
BUTTONS Hello|Help
```